# How to design a class with 10,000+ methods?

Tags: python, class, oop

I am writing code that automatically generates a maths test. I have written a lot of question templates (50 atm) which take in an argument (difficulty) and generate a question by randomly choosing some numbers etc. based on the difficulty.

For example,

```py
def question(difficulty):
    a = random.randint(1, 10 ** difficulty)
    b = random.randint(1, 10 ** difficulty)
    return [f"What is {a} + {b}?", str(a + b)]
```

The output is a question and its answer. I hope to have more than 10,000 of these functions in the future. What would be the best way to store these functions? I thought of making each a class, and each version would be an instance, but that would mean a lot of classes. I've thought of having a single class with 10,000 methods, which also seemed impractical. Is there a better way to structure my project?

Comment: Can you clarify what you are asking? Functions are things by themselves, they don't need to be stored in a class. Why not create 10,000 of these functions and be done with it?

Comment: I dont see how you can create 10,000 of these, they'll all be the same where you have an operator and some numbers

Comment: You don't need 10,000 methods; you just need *one* method that accepts `a` and `b` as arguments. (Or more generally, take a format string as well rather than hard-coding an f-string.)

Comment: Like anything else in programming, look for the *commonalities* between the functions, abstract them out, and replace 10,000 functions with a single parameterized function.

Comment: The questions are going to be much more detailed, covering all of mathematics and possibly other subjects. Especially when you include word problems, the number of questions will go up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mashing code and data together. The best way to separate them is to create a configuration file (or a file where will you store the question templates) written in a DSL ([domain-specific language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language)).

It could be based on a common format such as JSON (or it can be completely different, that is your choice):

```json
{
    "addition_1": {
        "parameters": {
            "a": "random(1, 10 ** difficulty)"},
            "b": "random(1, 10 ** difficulty)"}
        },
        template: "What is {a} + {b}?",
        result: "a+b"
    }
}
```

Just be sure to correctly parse these expressions and don't use functions like `eval` or `exec`.

Another idea is to use a python file as a configuration file like this which you can then import and use the data (this is still mashing code with data but it is better than writing 10000 methods and it is easier than writing your own DSL, I'm, however, not sure how scalable it is):

```py
def generator_1(difficulty):
    return random.randint(1, 10 ** difficulty)

questions_arithmetic = [
    Question({
        "a": generator_1,
        "b": generator_1
    }, "What is {a} + {b}?", lambda a, b: a+b),
    Question({
        "a": generator_1,
        "b": generator_1
    }, "What is {a} * {b}?", lambda a, b: a*b),
]
```

where `Question` is an object consisting of the parameters for the question (and functions which are used to generate them), the template for the question text and a function that calculates the result. This kind of Python-based configuration is for example used by Django. However, I don't think this approach is useable for applications requiring the exchange and modification of these configuration files by users.

You could also use a database and store the data in tables. This may be an even more scalable solution because databases are usually very performant (faster than simple configuration files).

Comment: You are still mashing code and data together unless you plan on parsing these strings rather than `eval`ing them. The DSL is the way to go here.

Comment: @chepner You are right, using `eval` is also a terrible solution, I'm editing the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this seems like the way to go. I'm not sure how to parse them though. What does using the DSL mean?

Comment: Ignore that since you've updated your answer.

Comment: Using a DSL means that you write your own language suited for a concrete problem. In Python you can parse the language using something like pyparsing. Wikipedia on DSL: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language